# Extracting dominant color from specific area of video frame using opencv and python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to create a Rubik's Cube Scanner. My idea is to draw 9 squares on screen and then ask the user to place the Rubik's cube in those 9 squares. Then, I will extract the dominant color from each of the 9 squares.

I have written the code, but I am facing issues in recognizing the colors. For instance, if I show it a red-solved side of the cube, the bgr values do not show a higher R value.

input frame:

[image: input frame]

(cropped the image to only necessary section)

`Palatted` Image:

[image]

```py
import cv2
# import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1366)
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 768)

x1 = 40
y1 = 40
spacing = 30    

def get_dominant_color(pil_img, palette_size=6):
    # Resize image to speed up processing
    img = pil_img.copy()
    image = Image.fromarray(img)
    # image.thumbnail((100, 100))

    # Reduce colors (uses k-means internally)
    
    paletted = image.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=palette_size)

    # Find the color that occurs most often
    palette = paletted.getpalette()
    color_counts = sorted(paletted.getcolors(), reverse=True)
    palette_index = color_counts[0][1]
    dominant_color = palette[palette_index*3:palette_index*3+3]

    return dominant_color

rectangle_Color = (255,0,0)
r1_1 = [x1, y1, x1*2,y1*2]
r1_2 = [x1 * 2 + spacing, y1, x1*2 + x1 + spacing, y1*2]
r1_3 = [x1*2 + x1 + spacing + spacing,y1,x1*2 + x1 + spacing + spacing + x1,y1*2]
r2_1 = [ x1,y1 * 2 + spacing,x1*2,y1*2 + y1 + spacing]
r2_2 = [x1 * 2 + spacing,y1 * 2 + spacing,x1*2 + x1 + spacing,y1*2 + y1 + spacing]
r2_3 = [x1*2 + x1 + spacing + spacing,y1 * 2 + spacing,x1*2 + x1 + spacing + spacing + x1,y1*2 + y1 + spacing]
r3_1 = [x1,y1 * 2 + spacing + y1 + spacing,x1*2,y1*2 + y1 + spacing + spacing + y1]
r3_2 = [x1 * 2 + spacing,y1 * 2 + spacing + y1 + spacing,x1*2 + x1 + spacing,y1*2 + y1 + spacing + y1 + spacing]
r3_3 = [x1*2 + x1 + spacing + spacing,y1 * 2 + spacing + y1 + spacing, x1*2 + x1 + spacing + spacing + x1,y1*2 + y1 + spacing + spacing + y1]

side_1 = []

while(True):
    ret, frame = video.read()
   
    # dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(src,(5,5),cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

    #first row
    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r1_1[0], r1_1[1] ), ( r1_1[2], r1_1[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )
    rect1_img = frame[r1_1[1]: r1_1[1] + r1_1[0],r1_1[0]:r1_1[0] + r1_1[1]]
    rect1 = get_dominant_color(rect1_img)
    
    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r1_2[0], r1_2[1] ), ( r1_2[2], r1_2[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )
    rect2_img = frame[r1_2[1]: r1_2[1] + r1_2[0],r1_2[0]:r1_2[0] + r1_2[1]]
    rect2 = get_dominant_color(rect2_img)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r1_3[0], r1_3[1] ), ( r1_3[2], r1_3[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )    
    rect3_img = frame[r1_3[1]: r1_3[1] + r1_3[0],r1_3[0]:r1_3[0] + r1_3[1]]
    rect3 = get_dominant_color(rect3_img)

    #second row
    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r2_1[0], r2_1[1] ), ( r2_1[2], r2_1[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )
    rect4_img = frame[r2_1[1]: r2_1[1] + r2_1[0],r2_1[0]:r2_1[0] + r2_1[1]]
    rect4 = get_dominant_color(rect4_img)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r2_2[0], r2_2[1] ), ( r2_2[2], r2_2[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )    
    rect5_img = frame[r2_2[1]: r2_2[1] + r2_2[0],r2_2[0]:r2_2[0] + r2_2[1]]
    rect5 = get_dominant_color(rect5_img)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r2_3[0], r2_3[1] ), ( r2_3[2], r2_3[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )    
    rect6_img = frame[r2_3[1]: r2_3[1] + r2_3[0],r2_3[0]:r2_3[0] + r2_3[1]]
    rect6 = get_dominant_color(rect6_img)

    #third row
    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r3_1[0], r3_1[1] ), ( r3_1[2], r3_1[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )
    rect7_img = frame[r3_1[1]: r3_1[1] + r3_1[0],r3_1[0]:r3_1[0] + r3_1[1]]
    rect7 = get_dominant_color(rect7_img)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r3_2[0], r3_2[1] ), ( r3_2[2], r3_2[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )    
    rect8_img = frame[r3_2[1]: r3_2[1] + r3_2[0],r3_2[0]:r3_2[0] + r3_2[1]]
    rect8 = get_dominant_color(rect8_img)

    cv2.rectangle(frame, ( r3_3[0], r3_3[1] ), ( r3_3[2], r3_3[3] ), rectangle_Color, 2 )    
    rect9_img = frame[r3_3[1]: r3_3[1] + r3_3[0],r3_3[0]:r3_3[0] + r3_3[1]]
    rect9 = get_dominant_color(rect9_img)

    side_1.append(rect1)
    side_1.append(rect2)
    side_1.append(rect3)
    side_1.append(rect4)
    side_1.append(rect5)
    side_1.append(rect6)
    side_1.append(rect7)
    side_1.append(rect8)
    side_1.append(rect9)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break
    else:
        with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
            for item in side_1:
                color = str(item[0]) + "," + str(item[1]) + "," + str(item[2])
                f.write(color + "\n")
        side_1 = []
    

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: did you check your paletted image? why do this step at all? just calculate the average of each square.  please at least provide your input and paletted image. also you should consider using loops instead of hardcoding everything for 9 squares

Comment: Are you scanning photographs, or is this some sort of artificial Rubik's cube where the user selects the colors manually?

Comment: @nick012000 No, it's not a photograph, the user will scan the rubik's cube through the camera, so when the program runs, the camera starts and then the user need to place the a side of the cube in the 9 squares ( refer to 1st image ) and i will extract the colors from it

.No, the user does not manually select the colors, i have created a full working simulation of rubiks cube in javascript, now the idea is to allow the user to scan a irl rubik's cube and apply the color config in the simulator ( the simulator is 100% done )

I am struggling with the scanning part cause i am new to opencv

Comment: this might help you with color recognition: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/

As @Piglet suggested, just take an average of all the pixels inside your square. And please DO use for loops.

Comment: @Piglet After you said, i checked the palatted image and have uploaded it, i don't understand it why it's apearing black ( i saved it using the imwrite("testing.jpg", np.float32(palatted))). I am new to opencv and was searching various ways to do this, i already thought of averaging the colours, as you said, but for some reason this seemed more promising to me so i thought i would implement this first. Sorry for the mess, this is more of a rough code, later i will be refactoring it so that i can scan rubiks cube of various sizes, but for now i just decided to hard code the sizes

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Thanks for the resource, i appreciate it. I will read and try implementing it and see how it goes. Sorry for the mess, i will be using loops, for me scanning / opencv is the hard part, so i thought i would get that out of the way first and then focus on loops / refactoring ( extending it to bigger cubes etc.. )